# How do I create arch linux partitions if fdisk says they're busy?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, partition

I'm going through the [Arch Linux Installation Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide), but when I got to the part where I needed to create partitions on `/dev/sda`, after inserting my live USB with the `fdisk` utility, the following happened.

1. I deleted all partitions on `/dev/sda`.
2. I created a partitions according to the table in the directions, but
3. When I tried to write the partitions, it gave me the error:

```
Failed to remove partition 1 from system: Device or resource busy
Failed to add partition 1 to system: Device or resource busy
Failed to add partition 2 from: system: Device or resource busy
```

What's going on? I know Arch Linux ain't easy, but I've got time.

fdisk -l outputs
[image: Output of fdisk -l][image]

Comment: Could it be that `/dev/sda` is your USB stick and e.g. `/dev/sdb` is the one you want to partition? Check the output of `fdisk -l`.

Comment: @Freddy fdisk -l doesn't output any more /dev/sdX s.

Comment: So what is the output? Are any other drives detected? Is the target drive a SATA HDD/SSD or a NVMe SSD? Please add the details to your question.

Comment: @Freddy I don't understand what SATA HDD/SSD or NVMe SSD mean.

Comment: It's about the interface type of your drive. If you have a newer NVMe device, then the device name would be `/dev/nvmeXnY` instead of `/dev/sdX` if it was correctly detected. 
This is why you should add the output of `fdisk -l` to your question.

Comment: @Freddy I updated it with a pic of fdisk -l

Comment: If you want to partition the SD/MMC card, use `fdisk /dev/mmcblk0`.

Comment: @Freddy is that what I need to install Arch Linux on my hard drive?